# best practice to avoid partial specialization of alias templates

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I'm now working on implementing a standard, and there is a template class `vector_class` defined in the specification. I just used alias template

```
template <class T, class Allocator=std::allocator<T>>
using vector_class = std::vector<T, Allocator>;
```

In the later work, I have a function call `vector_class::data()` which returns a pointer with the type of `T*`.

Everything works fine except `T` is `bool`. As you all know, `std::vector<bool>` is a possibly space-efficient specialization of `std::vector` for the type `bool`, and it don't implement the member function `data`, and actually the return type of `vector<bool>::data()` on my machine is `void`. Now here is the problem, we have some code like:

```
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    vector_class<T> buffer;

    T* ptr; // this pointer is defined in the specification thus it is indispensable

    A(T* data, size_t size) {
        buffer.resize(size);
        ptr = buffer.data();
        std::copy(data, data + size, ptr);
    }
};
```

If the `T` is `bool`, the compiler will raise an error that cannot convert the type `void` to `bool*` in the code `ptr = buffer.data()`.

Well, for my current implementation, it is the last option to avoid using `std::vector` but the alternative in Boost. What I expect is something like partial specialization of alias templates but unluckily it is not allowed according to the C++ standard. Therefore, I want to ask, if there any other way to deal with such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a partial specialization of proxy class to be used with alias template:

```
template<typename T, typename Allocator> class
vector_class_impl final
{
    public: using type = std::vector<T, Allocator>;
};

template<typename Allocator> class
vector_class_impl<bool, Allocator> final
{
    public: using type = something_else<bool, Allocator>;
};

template <typename T, typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>>
using vector_class = typename vector_class_impl<T, Allocator>::type;
```

Comment: yeah, this is a good solution. Now I guess the my step is to implement a container specially for `bool`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This probably can't be helped, so you'll need to do slightly more work:

```
template <class T, class Allocator=std::allocator<T>>
struct vector_class: std::vector<T, Allocator>
{
    using std::vector<T, Allocator>::vector;
        // and member types too
};

template<class Allocator>
struct vector_class<bool, Allocator>
{
    // recreate the whole vector interface here
};
```

Comment: thanks. In this way, I only need to rewrite all the necessary constructors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specialize whole `class A` template for `bool`, replacing the `vector_bool<T>` with something else like [`boost::container::vector<T>`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/boost/container/vector.html).

Comment: yeah, this is also a good way if the there re not too much code in the `class A`, but except the `buffer`, other code is just coped from the common `class A`, making it hard to maintain. Besides, if I decide to use `boost`, why not just use it as alias? :)

Comment: @tianshilei1992 This can be solved by having common template base class for both the main template and the specialization.